# How to add album art with ffmpeg while converting webm to mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, webm

I have been trying trying to add an album  art while converting webm to mp3 at one go

The code below works but doesn't add the album art. Any help

**`ffmpeg -i file.webm  -i it.jpeg   -c:v copy -map 1 -map 0    -f mp3 -vn audio-out.mp3`**

Comment: Try to add `-id3v2_version 3`. Ex: `ffmpeg -i file.webm -i it.jpeg -c:v copy -map 1 -map 0 -id3v2_version 3 -vn -f mp3 audio-out.mp3`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to convert to MP3?  It's undoubtedly a loss in quality from whatever codec you're using inside WebM right now, especially since you're likely re-encoding from a lossy source already.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a way to do this

```
ffmpeg -i  file.webm -i it.jpeg -map 0 -map 1 audio-out.mp3
```